# Checkbox association with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

My checkboxes doesn't work correctly in association.
I have a jquery UI tab with 4 tabs. the last 2 tabs must be deactivated if i check in my first tab a checkbox. That works fine.
But i have an association with my checkboxes from the first with the second tab. So when i check SC1 than must be every checkboxes who begins with SC1 checked. And if the SC1 is checked and after than i check SC2 then must be all SC2 tabs been checked and also still all checkboxes of SC1. It doesn't works and i hope you can find a solution.

```
$('#tabs-1').click(function() {
$("#ARtabs").tabs({disabled: [2,3]});


if ($('.SC1T').is(':checked')) 
        {
        $('.SC1').attr('checked' ,'checked');
     }
    else
    if ($('.SC2T').is(':checked'))
            {
                $('.SC2').attr('checked' ,'checked');
            }     
    else
    if ($('.SC3T').is(':checked'))
            {
                $('.SC3').attr('checked' ,'checked');
            }     
    else
    {
        $('.SC1').removeAttr('checked');
        $('.SC2').removeAttr('checked');
        $('.SC3').removeAttr('checked');
        $("#ARtabs").tabs("option", "disabled", []);
    }
});
```

Here is my Problem in [demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/achillix/TqJqH/)

THX in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the else statements. If one of your condition is true, the following conditions will not be checked.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#ARtabs" ).tabs({
       collapsible: true,
       fx: { opacity: 'toggle' }
    });
});

$('#tabs-1').click(function() {

   var oneIsChecked = false;
   if ($('.SC1T').is(':checked')){
       oneIsChecked = true;
       $('.SC1').attr('checked' ,'checked');
   }else{
       $('.SC1').removeAttr('checked');
   }

   if ($('.SC2T').is(':checked')){
        oneIsChecked = true;
        $('.SC2').attr('checked' ,'checked');
   }else{
       $('.SC2').removeAttr('checked');
   }     

    if ($('.SC3T').is(':checked')){
        oneIsChecked = true;
        $('.SC3').attr('checked' ,'checked');
    }else{
       $('.SC3').removeAttr('checked');
    }     


   if(oneIsChecked){ 
       $("#ARtabs").tabs({disabled: [2,3]});
   }else{
       $('.SC1').removeAttr('checked');
       $('.SC2').removeAttr('checked');
       $('.SC3').removeAttr('checked');
       $("#ARtabs").tabs("option", "disabled", []);
   } 
});
```

Comment: The approach is a bit different, but more or less the same concept: http://jsfiddle.net/axelmichel/TqJqH/1/